# ReCaptcha v2 implementation in PHP

Tags: php, recaptcha

So I have been having trouble implementing Recaptcha v2

Here is my form code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="html_element"></div>
<input type="file" name="file" style="font-family:'PSR';">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

And this is the recaptcha part of code (same file but tried splitting into 2 before)

```
$secret = 'the secret';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$googleobj = json_decode($response);
echo $googleobj;
$verified = $googleobj->success;

if($verified === true)
      {
```

Whatever I do $verified always returns false. The echo part was me trying to debug but that has given me another error followed by a HTTP error 500.

```
PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Vardump of $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] returns

```
string(334) "03AF6jDqXmI34YXuv1jIkgqHFo7TcjWbOq4-LJ_aTBRyzDld5BytgSe4ck_dolLm3C9CUzxela7LWa7hYJeJfEBONPPsx3ol7Ch-7SY8I9WyAFEy-iiGqwxZBY41gCSw7dfT42doqg-FIxwZweLOsH5YEf8i-L2QgkAJEd_PrWc9m2Uf6ZNbTDqCNr3VFqF8_0I-gS0Rhj9Z5XXwQLC9LeNfSWhI0DkpYNgK-hO4nGfEsaZT0PMlAg9DbHh9CzKDUzPpguVxz1zw0FP8CgwyBd9sgzpR4LfAoPuduGj0Z0wVcqbQ-CTifFtH7kCJuNG6bCDEufYfntj-8L"
```

Sorry if this is very basic stuff but im new to PHP

Comment: the error was on the echo line. other from that nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `echo` an stdObject.

```
$googleobj = json_decode($response);
echo $googleobj;
```

This does not work, because `$googleobj` is not a string, it's an object. When using the `echo` command, PHP tries to convert whatever is being `echo`'d into a string, which it cannot do with an object.

Instead, you could do:

```
$googleobj = json_decode($response);
print_r($googleobj);
```

Or simply remove the `echo` line completely.

Comment: This helped me solve the issue. Turns out the secret i had was slightly different to the one in my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RealistikDash Glad that I could help

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
$response = file_get_contents(as you have it);

$googleobj = json_decode($response, TRUE);
$verified = $googleobj['success'];

if($verified === true) {
    ...
```

The parameter `true` in `json_decode` makes it an associative array. So you can access it like a normal array.
Take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information

Comment: It has nothing to do with how they are trying to access the object/array (They are accessing the object correctly). The error is from trying to echo an object, which would still be a problem if it were an array

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is what worked for me. As you can see I removed the echo statement. It's just the way I prefer.

Comment: Yes, but the answer is to remove the echo statement, that's what actually fixed it. The OP is currently already using the object correctly, is there any good reason why they should switch to an array (even though that won't solve their problem directly) besides personal preference?

Comment: Turns out my secret was slightly off. Thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: The OP can choose which way to take. Isn't it allowed to show up different ways to solve a problem?

Comment: @Johnny To be clear, I have no problem with you suggesting they use  an array instead of an object :) Consider it this way; your answer basically is stating that the error is because they are not using the `TRUE` flag in `json_decode()`, which is not the real problem. There is nothing wrong with suggesting using the `TRUE` flag, but you should also touch on the fact that _this will still not work because you can't echo an array_. Your _code_ may reflect this, but your overall answer does not. Your answer does not solve the problem, unless OP just copies the code and reads nothing else.

Comment: @Johnny And on top of that, changing `$googleobj` to an array may cause more problems if they rely on this being an object later on in the code.